# Used @font-face, and now my font is too bold

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

So I'm coding a website for the Tech Club at my school and I used the "@font-face" rule to use a custom font. The font was utilized, but for some reason it's . . . really bold. Dark, I guess. Any ideas on what's going on? Oh, and I'm using the latest Chrome browser.

Code:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: War Eagle;
            src: url("wareagle.ttf");
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 50pt;
            font-family: War Eagle;
        }
```

Comment: When using `font-size` you should use `px` instead of `pt`

Comment: you can use em also. em is a browser value. By default all browsers font size set to be 16PX (approx), So if you define 1em it will be 16 px.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the font you are using?

[War Eagle Font](http://www.dafont.com/war-eagle.font)

Notice how `wareagle.ttf` is bold? You need to add `wareagle3D.ttf` or the `ttf` of whatever style you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Use separate `@font-face` for normal and bold style, and use `font-style` and `font-weight` for each; the best way to embed font, recommended by experts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'War Eagle';
    src: url('fonts/wareagle.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "War Eagle";
    src: url("fonts/wareagle_bold.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: The `src` setting is the same, so you would be declaring the same font file as both normal and bold.

Comment: Now the answer is relevant *if* the font has a bold typeface *and* you wish to use it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks, it is because of your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, `h1` elements have `font-weight: bold`. Since your code does not declare a bold typeface, browsers will apply algorithmic (synthetic) bolding. So add the following in order to use the declared typeface as-is:

```
h1 { font-weight: normal }
```

You should also use a tool like [FontSquirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), since not all browsers support TTF format.